# Aligning a Div element in a Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to align the `div` element inside a `div` to center.

[image].

The image shows that the inner `div` elements are not aligned in center.

My code is given below

```
<div class="row ph">
 <div class="col-sm-3 phi"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-3 phi"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-3 phi"></div>
</div>
```

My `style.css` is given below.

```
.ph
{
background-color: green;
position : relative;
margin : 0 auto;
}

.phi
{
background-color: yellow;
width: 20%;
margin: 50px;
height: 250px;
}
```

when I searched for the solution, I found about the `position` and `margin auto` attributes. Can you help me with the solution?

Comment: please add some description for what you want to do , you want to align your inner divs in the middle of the outer div ?

Comment: yes. that is my question

Answer (score 0):

so simple , just add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to get the horizontally inner divs
and add the `text-align: center;` to the outer div to center them

your css may be something like this

```
.ph
{
background-color: green;
position : relative;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.phi
{
background-color: yellow;
width: 20%;
margin: 30px;
height: 250px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

check out :
http://jsfiddle.net/xkqTR/2118/

Comment: not getting the output @Hassan still getting the same output in the chrome i.e. local host

Comment: @anandmbs you want the output you mentioned in your question ? the picture you've attached ? or you want to center your inner divs ? please check out the jsfiddle link

Comment: the output in the JS fiddle works fine. But the output in local system does not work

Comment: please make sure that you have been cleared your cache , from my localhost , http://i.imgur.com/QBaUlkk.png

Comment: I would try and get back to you @hassan. But I tried in incognito window also. But didnt work.

Comment: would you try the code in jsfiddle in a new html document to just test the functionality ?? , and please try to add width: 100% to you .ph